# android 4.0 Dialog gets canceled when touched outside of dialog window

Tags: dialog, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Hi I am facing the problem on ICS like `dialog` is `dismissed` when we click outside `dialog` window, due to which I am getting problem like I don't get any confirmation from user.

Please help.

Comment: For some reason starting with ICS they made the default `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` to `true`. The change doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (no surprise). Just clarification for anyone reading.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Check [this method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)) from the Android Developers site for dialog.

Try using the

`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside (boolean cancel)`

Pass a boolean value to enable/disable dialog behaviour when touched outside of the dialog window.

Also go through these links:

[How do I fire an event when click occurs outside a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516287/android-click-event-outside-a-dialog)

[How to cancel an Dialog themed like Activity when touched outside the window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650246/how-to-cancel-an-dialog-themed-like-activity-when-touched-outside-the-window)

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Default should be false, this caused a lot of problems for my users.

Answer (score 15):

You may use

```
dialog.setCancelable(true/false);
```

OR

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true/false);
```

For the latest vesrions of Android;

It will disable outSideTouching event.

Comment: yes we can but that will disable cancellation of dialog on back key press.. many of the times you dont want ur dialog to get cancelled when touched outside but u want to handle the back key press events for dialog..

Comment: Yes you are right @nishi . So I edited my answer and added a new option setCancelOnTouchOutSide(T/F) event :P

Answer (score 13):

```
dialog.setCancelable(false)
```

Dialog **CAN NOT** cancel when touch out side **OR** press `BACK` key

```
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
```

Dialog **CAN NOT** cancel when touched outside **BUT ABLE** to canceled when press `BACK` key