# how to stop on Touch out side in dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog

I am using dialog fragment, 
when I click on fab i will display the dialog , but I have to `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` when I do the app is crashing !

so , how I can stop touch out side

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            addAction add = new addAction();
            add.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);


            add.show(fm,"fragment_edit_name");

        }});
```

and i got this error

```
09-26 13:06:21.997 2890-2890/com.example.todo.todoapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at com.example.todo.todoapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:94)
```

line 94 is     add.getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: show the `stack trace`, it will help in understanding the problem

Comment: Please share your crash logs

Comment: i edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` in side `oncreatedialog()` method.

Example

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), getThemeId());        
        final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.settings, null);
        dialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.action_settings));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        return dialog;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Window window = dialog.getWindow();
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

        dialog.show();
```

Details 
    [Android click event outside a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516287/android-click-event-outside-a-dialog)