# How to know when is clicked outside the dialog box - Android

Tags: android, dialog

I am working with a dialog, and two `negativeButton` and `positiveButton`. Nevertheless, I would like to change the behaviour when pressing outside the box. I have checked, and all the questions I have found about this topic are about hiding the `AlertDialog` when clicking outside `dialog.dimiss()`, but this is not my question. I want to know if there is a `listener` which allows me to switch this behaviour (would like to call other methods and remove other variables).

**JAVA**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(m_activity);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Navigation");
    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Choose Mode");
    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Navigation", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            m_navigationManager.startNavigation(m_route);
            m_map.setTilt(60);
            startForegroundService();
        }

        ;
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Simulation", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
            m_activity.findViewById(R.id.address_form).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            m_navigationManager.simulate(m_route, 30);//Simualtion speed is set to 45 m/s
            m_map.setTilt(60);
            startForegroundService();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: @You want click outside to call other methods but keep dialog from dismiss?

Comment: Check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28709752/8399393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `DismissListener` for example:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

    }
});
```

#### This callback will be called when the dialog is dismissed for any reason (also when user choose "positive" or "negative button)!

Comment: @Maybe He want to click outside to call other methods but keep dialog from dismiss

Comment: Works like charm. I will set it as correct in 8 minutes

Comment: Yes. But stackoverflow does not allow to set it as correct until 10 minutes after posting it. You were too fast :)

Comment: Hah! Happy that helped :)